# How to setup Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01in tutorial MappingFromLoggedData

Tags: navigation, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am new to ros

I am running the tutorial MappingFromLoggedData and using the existing bag recommended in the tutorial. However, when I run rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan, the map in rviz is some preset map. If i try to create my own bag, it will show "/use_sim_time set to true and no clock published. still waiting for valid time." Is there anything that I do it wrongly? Or is the topic i subscribed to during the rosrun gmapping is wrong?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81396/how-to-setup-hokuyo-urg-04lx-ug01in-tutorial-mappingfromloggeddata/) by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
before recroding your bag run $rosparam set use_sim_time false

let me know if it works.

@lili Meng. if you get same problem, then add a comment instead of your answer to keep the thread organized.

---

Originally posted by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) with karma: 167 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0